# Google Play Store App: getting reviewed without publishing

Tags: google-play, publishing

I am trying to launch an app onto the Google Play Store.
However I want to avoid actually launching it, but still get it reviewed so that it can be published (without any changes) at a later date. This would avoid another review once I actually want it published and available to download.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have already gone through the process of Internal/Beta.. testing.

Comment: Use managed publishing

Comment: @user14678216 How do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in google play console when you are inside your app
in the left manu bar click on the Publishing overview tab
then on the right side of the screen click on turn on managed publishing,
then select if you want to manually publish or leave it in auto publish mode.